# ListView HitTest returning wrong value after popup menu is shown

Tags: listview, vb6, popup, popupmenu, hittest

I have a ListView method named listView_MouseUp that selects an item in my ListView if the HitTest returns something. After that, I test if I clicked with the right mouse button. Then I open a popup menu for modifying the selected item:

```
Private Sub listView_MouseUp(Button As Integer, Shift As Integer, X As Single, Y As Single)
    Dim selectedListItem As ListItem
    Set selectedListItem = listView.HitTest(X, Y)
    If Not selectedListItem Is Nothing Then
        ' Select the item and load some text fields
        If Button = vbRightButton Then
            Me.PopupMenu popupChangeDocument
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

If I click (left mouse button) a second time (on the previously selected item) the X and Y coordinates are correct (new values) and the popup menu is not visible anymore.

If I click on an empty area of the ListView X and Y stay the same and the popup menu opens at the clicks position.

Why are the values ​​of X and Y not updated?

Comment: [This link from vb-helper](http://www.vb-helper.com/howto_listview_popup_menu.html) should help.

Answer (score 0):

> [This link from vb-helper](http://www.vb-helper.com/howto_listview_popup_menu.html) should help.

@BillHileman Thanks for the link. Unfortunately, it didn't help with this problem. But in the process of testing your answer, I found the issue:

There was a **DoEvents** at the end of the listView_MouseUp method that caused this strange behaviour.

Comment: You definitely don't want to perform a DoEvents inside an event handler, which is what these "methods" really are.  You can get cascading problems unless you anticipate it with safety fall-out code, which is another discussion entirely.  Glad you found your issue.